# Slack API ProtocolError/ConnetionError but still working

Tags: python, flask

I want to post a message to Slack using a bot, so I created a service to do that (in Flask). Now I call this service using requests (Django).

```
        data = json.loads(json.dumps(_data))



        headers = {
            'Content-Type': "application/json",
            'cache-control': "no-cache",
            }

        r = requests.post(url, json=data, auth=(username, password), headers=headers)
```

While the bot is posting on Slack and everything is working like expected, I'm having an error message and this is confusing:

```
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError:('Connection aborted.',
BadStatusLine("HTTP/1.0 0{  
   'ok':True,
   'channel':'xxxxxxxxxxx',
   'ts':'1563789414.000600',
   'message':{  
      'type':'message',
      'subtype':'bot_message',
      'text':'xxxxxxxxxxx',
      'ts':'1563789414.000600',
      'username':'xxxxxxxxxx',
      'bot_id':'xxxxxxxxxxx'
   },
   'headers':{  
      'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      'Content-Length':'220',
      'Connection':'keep-alive',
      'Date':'Mon, 22 Jul 2019 09:56:54 GMT',
      'Server':'Apache',
      'X-Content-Type-Options':'nosniff',
      'X-Slack-Req-Id':'1851de9e-59ec-45a7-be61-107a092e6371',
      'X-OAuth-Scopes':'admin,identify,bot,groups:read,usergroups:read,chat:write:user,chat:write:bot,groups:write',
      'Expires':'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT',
      'Cache-Control':'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
      'Access-Control-Expose-Headers':'x-slack-req-id, retry-after',
      'X-XSS-Protection':'0',
      'X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes':'chat:write:bot',
      'Vary':'Accept-Encoding',
      'Pragma':'no-cache',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'slack-route, x-slack-version-ts',
      'Strict-Transport-Security':'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload',
      'Referrer-Policy':'no-referrer',
      'Content-Encoding':'gzip',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
      'X-Via':'haproxy-www-n3u5',
      'X-Cache':'Miss from cloudfront',
      'Via':'1.1 d6561aeeccb210202cf78b99f07c5235.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)',
      'X-Amz-Cf-Pop':'CDG3-C2',
      'X-Amz-Cf-Id':'Y4CJp-NBWSkdNYXm8bfTCdhuFPL1sn6johYZqkmv_wsXfaq0kcA7TQ=='
   }
}\r\n"))
```

Also, the Python http client is raising a bad status line:

[image]

Calling the service using a simple curl works fine without any error:

```
curl -d "@data.json"  -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -X POST http://0.0.0.0:8004/ --user xxxxx:xxxxx
```

Do you see the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I changed

```
return str(data)
```

by

```
return jsonify(data), 200
```

in my Flask service.

Comment: Awesome! Now it would be fantastic if you could please add the part of the code where this error was fixed to the question, so others would be able to follow it.